# How does the .split() method work in java?

Tags: java, string, split, java.util.scanner

I am using Java and have been trying to split my string input into 3 parts. For example, my input will be "AND 1 1", and I am expecting it to go into my if-loop where the condition is parts[0] == "AND". But this is not the case, and I am not sure why.

My code is listed below

```
Scanner stringInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = stringInput.next();
System.out.printf("%s\n", input);
String[] parts = input.split(" ");

if (parts[0] == "AND") {
    if (parts[1] == parts[2] && parts[1] == "1") 
        System.out.printf("1\n");
    else 
        System.out.printf("0\n");
}
else {
    if (parts[1] == "1" || parts[2] == "0")
        System.out.printf("1\n");
    else 
        System.out.printf("0\n");
}
```

Comment: Make sure to compare strings with `.equals()`

Comment: NOOOOOOOO... It's still morning... why `==`?... :__(

Comment: if loop ? maybe it's a conditional statement

Answer (score 2):

You are using `stringInput.next()` which will not read spaces. So that is the problem.
Use `stringInput.nextLine()` instead of `stringInput.next()`

`String input=stringInput.nextLine();` is correct when you are working with text that contains space.

Here is the edited code.

```
Scanner stringInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = stringInput.nextLine();
System.out.printf("%s\n", input);
String[] parts = input.split(" ");

if (parts[0] == "AND") {
    if (parts[1] == parts[2] && parts[1] == "1") 
        System.out.printf("1\n");
    else 
        System.out.printf("0\n");
}
else {
    if (parts[1] == "1" || parts[2] == "0")
        System.out.printf("1\n");
    else 
        System.out.printf("0\n");
}
```

You probably might have got an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: what is if (parts[0] == "AND") isn't it ALWAYS true since it checks wether both are objects of same type.

Comment: It checks references for equality not the values. When you write something in double quotes, it is treated as a String object. Now, "AND" is another string object and parts[0] is another String object. Now the references are checked. This is why equals() is a great method.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can not be sure that the string is the object you think it is. For this reason, you should not use `==` to compare objects, but use the `equals` function.

```
if (parts[0] == "AND")
```

should be

```
if (parts[0].equals("AND"))
```

Strings are immutable, so the functions will always return new strings, when they have to do something on them. For this reason, using `==` will only work in some particular cases, but never when you process them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
if (parts[0].toString().equals("AND")){
    if (parts[1].equals(parts[2]) && parts[1].equals("1")) 
        System.out.printf("1\n");
    else 
        System.out.printf("0\n");
}else {
    if (parts[1].equals("1") || parts[2].equals("0"))
        System.out.printf("1\n");
    else 
        System.out.printf("0\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! BTW I have checked that parts[0] is already of type String, so why is there a need for .toString()?

Comment: you can remove that thing

Comment: Since `parts` is a string array, there is no need for it to use `toString`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `String.split()` method in correct way. The `parts[0]` also contains the desired `"AND"` after using the method.

But the problem is you are checking equality of two strings using "`=="` instead of `equals` method. When you use `==` then it checks whether they are same reference of string while the `equals` method check the values of the string.

So your checking should be something like this

```
if (parts[0].equals("AND"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 parts[0].equals("AND") to check equality of `String`
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

- as JavaTechnical pointed out, you should use `stringInput.nextLine()` vs `stringInput.next()`
- as everyone pointed out, use `.equals()` vs `==`, here's a thread explaining why: [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)
- test against a known vs an unknown, reorder your test like so `"AND".equals(part[0])` should shield you from null pointer

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the  Devolus answers (I can't put comments in comments yet U_U)

== compares the references, it means that is only true if two variables are pointing to the same object

e.g.

```
  Object a =  new Car()
  Object b =   a  
  Object c =  new Car()





  (a == b) //true
  (a == c)  //false

  a.equals(b)  //true  
  a.equals(c)  //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using .substring(), for example:

```
String a = "AND 1 1"
b = a.substring(1,3)
c = a.substring(4,5)
System.out.println(b)
System.out.println(c)
```

Would print "AND" then "1"